# ASP.NET MVC project does not update view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm newbie to ASP.NET MVC projects and I face a problem.

I have my view that have just field for words and send them to the controller, but when I return view with data from database or API, it does not render it. When I debug this, I noticed that data passes in `index.cshtml` file, but just doesn't render it on the site.

Here are my controller methods:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new SearchViewModel
    {
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendWords([FromBody] List<string> keywords)
{
    var hash = _hashService.GetHash(keywords);
    string inputString = string.Join(" ", keywords);
    IEnumerable<SearchResult> searchResults = null;
    var query = await _queryService.GetQueryByHashAsync(hash);

    if (query != null)
    {
        searchResults = query.Results;
    }
    else
    {
        var yandexTask = _yandexService.Search(inputString);
        var googleTask = _googleService.Search(inputString);
        var bingTask = _bingService.Search(inputString);

        switch (await Task.WhenAny(yandexTask, googleTask, bingTask))
        {
            case var completedTask when completedTask == yandexTask:
                searchResults = await yandexTask;
                break;

            case var completedTask when completedTask == googleTask:
                searchResults = await googleTask;
                break;

            case var completedTask when completedTask == bingTask:
                searchResults = await bingTask;
                break;
        }

        await _queryService.InsertQueryAsync(new List<Query> 
        {
            new Query { QueryKeywordHash = hash, Results = searchResults }
        });
    }

    var viewModel = new SearchViewModel
    {
        Words = new List<string>(),
        SearchResults = searchResults
    };

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Here my `index.cshtml`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model WebApplication10.Views.Search.ViewModels.SearchViewModel

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: beige; height: 300px; text-align: center; padding-top: 50px;">
    <div>
        <input id="wordInput" type="text" />
        <button onclick="addWord()" class="btn btn-primary">Add word </button>
    </div>

    <div id="wordList">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Words.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                <span>@Model.Words[i]</span>
                <button onclick="editWord(@i)" class="btn-outline-primary">change</button>
                <button onclick="deleteWord(@i)" class="btn-danger">delete</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Results:</h3>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var result in Model.SearchResults)
            {
                <li>
                    <a href="@result.Url" target="_blank">@result.Url</a><br />
                    <span>@result.Snippet</span>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
   <form id="sendWordsForm" method="post">
       <button id="sendButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled onclick="sendWords()">send</button>
   </form>
</div>
  
@section Scripts {
    <script src="js/site.js">
    </script>
}
```

Here repository of this project.
https://github.com/DIDIVERG/TestMVC

Will appreciate any help for this issue

I've tried put SearchViewModelData in a row with services but didn't work, also when i put data directly in index method data renders.

Comment: what is framework version?

Comment: i use .net 6 version

Comment: Try `ModelState.Remove("Words");ModelState.Remove("SearchResults");` in your controller post action before returning the View

Comment: Not helped.  I think problem in way I return view because index() method calls twice with filled searchresult and then without any data and it renders the second call without data, but i can't understand why it calls twice

Answer (score 0):

first of all I suggest you to use try and catch to see error details if they happened.
I think you can not login to database,
I checked your code and its the detail.(of course I dont have access to database, but i am not sure it can help you , but check you code like this to know what is happening)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v8qo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQyK.png)

Comment: I think, connectiostring causes the error,check it .

Comment: Here is all right, data fetches, i think problem in way i return view because index() method calls twice with filled searchresult and then without any data and it renders the second call without data